# Páginação com ReactJS consumindo de uma API

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, react, paginação

Ontem estava com um problema em conseguir criar uma páginação com nodeJS para minha API e com ajuda da comunidade conseguiram me da um norte e consegui resolver aquela situação.

**Qual é a ideia?** Existe um banco MySQL com 37 registros de usuários e quero listar eles na minha página web.

**Qual é o problema?**. Acontece que estou consumindo está minha API no react e ela está me trazendo apenas os 10 primeiros registros e se eu passo na minha url exemplo: usuarios?page=2 ou usuarios?page=3, de nada adianta, pois continua trazendo apenas os 10 primeiros registros.

Imagem trazendo apenas os 10 primeiros registros:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Minha API:**

```
import axios from 'axios';
```

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL:'http://localhost:3010',
})

export default api;

**Consumindo a API**

```
  componentDidMount(){
  this.call();     
}

async call(){
    const r = await api('/usuarios');
//    console.log(r.data);
    this.setState({
        usuarios:r.data
    }) 
}
```

**Renderização no React**

```
render(){
    const { usuarios } = this.state;
    return(
    <div>
        {usuarios.map((items,index)=>{
            return(
                <li key={index}>
                    <p>id:{items.id}</p>
                    <p>Email:{items.email}</p>
                </li>
            )
        })}
    </div>
    );
}
```

**Query do Banco**

```
if(results){
        const rows = results.length; // Existe 37 registros no banco
        let { page = 1 } = req.query; // passando argumento pela url >> usuarios?page=1
        let calc = Math.ceil(rows/10); // calc recebe a quantidade de páginas existentes

        if(page == ''){
            page = 1;
        }

            let count = (page*10)-10;

        const qtd = connection.query(`SELECT * FROM usuarios_homos LIMIT 10 OFFSET ${count}`,(err,result,fields)=>{
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                }else{
                    res.send(result);
                }

            });
    }
```

**Rota no NodeJS**

```
router.get('/usuarios',queryController);
```

**Testes realizados no insomnia funcionam bem:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: cade aqui a `page` ??? `const r = await api('/usuarios');`

Comment: Cuidado!!! Na API, toda query que vem do req é do tipo string, então não esqueça de converter esse parâmetro para número antes de realizar as operações de paginação.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que você não está passando qual a página para o endpoint:

```
async call(page = 1){
    const r = await api('/usuarios', { params: { page  });
    this.setState({ usuarios: r.data }) ;
}
```

repare que você tem que passar o número da página correta ao chamar a função `call`

se quiser pegar o número da página da query string você pode pegar o valor da propriedade `location.search` que irá retornar algo do tipo `?page=2`, aí você pode manipular esta string para obter o parâmetro

Comment: hmn.. saquei, mais uma vez consegui avançar na minha aplicação de paginação,  utilizei>>   let params = window.location.search;
                 const r = await api('/usuarios'+  params ); .... Seria isso né?!